# Jsoup get class names for children

Tags: java, jsoup

I am new to Jsoup and I am not sure how to pull the following. I have an element that has several spans that I am trying to get to.

```
<div class="first inlineblock">
 <span class="float_lang_base_1">Prev. Close</span>
 <span class="float_lang_base_2 bold">175</span>
</div>
<div class="inlineblock">
 <span class="float_lang_base_1">Day's Range</span>
 <span class="float_lang_base_2 bold">173.35 - 176.9</span>
</div>
<div class="inlineblock">
 <span class="float_lang_base_1">Revenue</span>
 <span class="float_lang_base_2 bold">21.07B</span>
</div>
<div class="first inlineblock">
 <span class="float_lang_base_1">Open</span>
 <span class="float_lang_base_2 bold">174.45</span>
</div>
```

My code is below:

```
Element OverviewHeadline = doc1.select("div[class=\"clear overviewDataTable\"]").first();
        System.out.println("OverviewHeadline = " + OverviewHeadline.html());

        Elements elements = OverviewHeadline.children();            

        for (Element e : elements)
        {
            System.out.println("e = " + e.html());

            if (e.child(0).className() == "float_lang_base_1")
            {
                if (e.child(0).text() == "Prev. Close")
                {
                    sPreviousClose = e.child(1).text();
                }   
            }

            if (e.child(0).className() == "float_lang_base_1")
            {
                if (e.child(0).text() == "Day's Range")
                {
                    sDaysRange = e.child(1).text();
                    iLen = sDaysRange.length();
                    ipos = sDaysRange.indexOf(" - ");
                    sMarketLow = sDaysRange.substring(0, ipos);                     
                    sMarketHigh = sDaysRange.substring(ipos + 3, iLen - (ipos + 3)  );
                }   
            }

            if (e.child(0).className() == "float_lang_base_1")
            {
                if (e.child(0).text() == "Open")
                {
                    sOpen = e.child(1).text();
                }   
            }               
        }
```

I am unsure as to how to get to the classnames.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Below is how I got it to work.

```
Element OverviewHeadline = doc1.select("div[class=\"clear overviewDataTable\"]").first();

        Elements elements = OverviewHeadline.children();            

        for (Element e : elements)
        {
            String sBase1 = e.select("span[class=\"float_lang_base_1\"]").text();
            String sBase2 = e.select("span[class=\"float_lang_base_2 bold\"]").text();

            if (sBase1.equals("Prev. Close"))
            {
                sPreviousClose = sBase2;
            }               

            if (sBase1.equals("Day's Range"))
            {
                sDaysRange = sBase2;
            }

            if (sBase1.equals("Open"))
            {
                sOpen = sBase2;
            }   
        }
```

In selecting the children of the `OverviewHeadLine`, it got me to the `spans`; which I select by using the `sBase1` and `sBase2`. I could then determine the items that I needed. The `sBase1` is the **field name** and the `sBase2` is the **value**.

Comment: Can you explain why this solved the issue? For future readers this might be helpful.

Comment: In selecting the children of the OverviewHeadLine, it got me to the spans;which I select by using the sBase1 and sBase2.  I could then determine the items that I needed.  The sBase1 is the field name and the sBase2 is the value